# Enable "Login as Member" for Additional Member Groups

Tags: core-hacks

I'm trying to enable the "Login as Member" functionality for a non-Super Admin member group. Here's what I've done so far:

In `/system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/members.php`, line 534, I changed to:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('group_id') != 1 || $this->session->userdata('group_id') != 6)
        {
            show_error(lang('unauthorized_access'));
        }
```

In `/system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/members.php`, line 594, I changed to:

```
if ($this->session->userdata['group_id'] != 1 || $this->session->userdata['group_id'] != 6)
        {
            show_error(lang('unauthorized_access'));
        }
```

And in `/system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/myaccount.php`, line 167, I changed to:

```
if( ($this->session->userdata('group_id') == 1 || $this->session->userdata('group_id') == 6) && $this->id != $this->session->userdata('member_id') )
            {
                $vars['login_as_member'] = TRUE;
            } else {
                $vars['login_as_member'] = FALSE;
            }
```

However, after doing this, when I click the "Login as Member" link while logged in to either member group, I get this error:

> You are not authorized to access this page

Any suggestions on what else I can do to get this working?

EE 2.6.1

P.S. Yes, I'm documenting this! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is happend because of logic error in lines 534 & 594 - you need replace it to AND logic not OR

```
        if ($this->session->userdata('group_id') != 1 && $this->session->userdata('group_id') != 6)
        {
            show_error(lang('unauthorized_access'));
        }
```