# Logging in as another member? Skeleton key?

Tags: members, member-details, member-management, authentication

My members have a custom control panel that they log into. Is there a way I can possibly set some sort of skeleton key so I can log in as those members? In some cases, the admin needs to play the role of the members (for troubleshooting, etc.). Is this possible?

Comment: By custom cPanel do you mean the traditional method via the backend of "login as this user" won't work for you?

Comment: My users do not have access to EE's control panel. Instead, when they are logged in, they are redirected to a special control panel (the site is a membership site and the special control panel is sort of profile manager).

Comment: cPanel is the name of a specific piece of software for managing servers, which is nothing to do with expressionengine. If you are talking about control panels in the generic sense it would be better to avoid using the name cPanel as it is confusing.

Comment: Shouldn't matter as long as you're using the native member management and even if you've built a custom frontend control panel. If you (as super admin) go into EE control panel, view the member in question, then select "Login as Member" in the Member Administration sidebar section. Now visit the frontend and your custom control panel, and you will be logged in as that user.

Comment: if you still not complete this task - send me message. I have module for this, can send you for test. http://cl.ly/image/1n1k311I2K2V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is currently an add-on that would allow "login as member" functionality from the front-end (e.g. any other place then the EE control panel)

However you could write (or commission to let write) a small plugin, based on the login_as_member() and do_login_as_member() functions. As a starting point for development see this question about [Enable “Login as Member” for Additional Member Groups](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17082/enable-login-as-member-for-additional-member-groups)